# Material UI Autocomplete- Popper not STUCk to the component which rendered it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

Current Output of my Autocomplete is in the attached VIDEO Link wheree the atocomplete suggestions are dancing around the page as window scrolls : https://www.screencast.com/t/atbTdIaXpzu

I am trying to fix the Autocomplete suggestion to the Autocomplete control and somehow Auto Suggestions dropdown sticks to the autocomplete BUT the scrolling experience within the Autocomplete is not that smooth

Solution used as below :

Using AutoComplete Property *PopperComponent*  ={PopperMy}

```
const PopperMy = function (props) {
  return <Popper {...props} placement="bottom-start" disablePortal={true} />;
};
```

or this popperVariant :

```
<Popper
      {...props}
      disablePortal={true}
      placement="bottom-start"
      popperOptions={{ positionFixed: true }}
    />
```

Any suggestions and fixed are appreciated. Thanks !

Adding the file contents for reference here :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  TextInputField,
  InputLabelField,
  BoxField,
  CustomWhiteTooltip,
} from "../../atoms";
import Autocomplete, {
  createFilterOptions,
} from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import {
  IsArrayNotEmpty,
  IsNotEmpty,
  IsString,
  IsObject,
  IsFunction,
  ThrowException,
  IsObjectNotEmpty,
  ObjectHasKey,
  IsNotUndefined,
} from "../../../utility";
import UserMessages from "../../../constants/UserMessages";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { InfoIcon } from "../../../resources/ThemeIcons";
import { Popper } from "@material-ui/core";


const TypeaheadField = ({
  id = "",
  renderInputId = "",
  listOptions,
  mainListOptionsKey = IsString(mainListOptionsKey)
    ? mainListOptionsKey
    : "title",
  getPropertyFromSingleObject = IsString(getPropertyFromSingleObject)
    ? getPropertyFromSingleObject
    : false,
  //defaultSelected='',
  isCreatable = false,
  onChange,
  addNewLabel = "Add",
  disableClearable = false,
  className = "",
  textFieldClassName = "",
  isSelectMultiple = false,
  limitTags = -1,
  filterSelectedOptions = true,
  openOnFocus = true,
  blurOnSelect = false,
  labelAtTop = false,
  labelClassName = "",
  popupIcon,
  size = "small",
  disabled = false,
  variant = "standard",
  label = "",
  required = false,
  placeholder = "",
  fullWidth = true,
  value = "",
  ChipProps = {},
  inputLabelProps = {},
  helperText = "",
  error = false,
  onBlur = "",
  name = "",
  tooltipMessage = "",
  tooltipIcon = "",
  ...rest
}) => {
  /* Required props:  listOptions, onChange */
  const isListOptionsProvided = IsArrayNotEmpty(listOptions);
  const isOnChangeProvided = IsFunction(onChange);
  if (!isListOptionsProvided || !isOnChangeProvided) {
    //ThrowException(UserMessages.warnings.missingRequiredProps);
  }

  const [autovalue, setValue] = React.useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const IsMultipleSelectAllowed = isSelectMultiple === true;
    if (IsMultipleSelectAllowed) {
      setValue(autovalue && IsArrayNotEmpty(autovalue) ? autovalue : []);
    } else if (!IsMultipleSelectAllowed) {
      setValue(autovalue && IsNotEmpty(autovalue) ? autovalue : null);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleOnChange = (event, newValue) => {
    let selectedValue = newValue;

    if (newValue && IsObject(newValue)) {
      if (newValue[mainListOptionsKey]) {
        // Create a new value from the user input
        if (newValue.type === "new") {
          if (IsString(listOptions[0])) {
            selectedValue = newValue.value;
            listOptions.push(newValue.value);
          } else {
            selectedValue = newValue.value;
            listOptions.push({
              [mainListOptionsKey]: newValue.value,
            });
          }
        }
      } else {
        const LastObject = IsArrayNotEmpty(newValue)
          ? newValue[newValue.length - 1]
          : null;
        const IsNewValueAdded =
          LastObject && LastObject.type === "new" && LastObject.value;
        if (IsNewValueAdded) {
          // Create a new value from the user input
          const CurrentValues =
            autovalue && IsArrayNotEmpty(autovalue) ? [...autovalue] : [];
          if (IsString(listOptions[0])) {
            selectedValue = [...CurrentValues, LastObject.value];
            listOptions.push(LastObject.value);
          } else {
            selectedValue = [
              ...CurrentValues,
              { [mainListOptionsKey]: LastObject.value },
            ];
            listOptions.push({ [mainListOptionsKey]: LastObject.value });
          }
        }
      }
    }

    setValue(selectedValue);
    if (
      getPropertyFromSingleObject !== false &&
      isSelectMultiple === false &&
      IsObjectNotEmpty(selectedValue) &&
      ObjectHasKey(selectedValue, getPropertyFromSingleObject)
    ) {
      onChange(selectedValue[getPropertyFromSingleObject]);
      return;
    }
    onChange(selectedValue);
  };

  const handleFilterOptions = (options, params) => {
    const filter = createFilterOptions();
    const filtered = filter(options, params);

    // Suggest the creation of a new value
    const IsSuggestNewValue = params.inputValue !== "" && isCreatable === true;
    if (IsSuggestNewValue) {
      filtered.push({
        value: params.inputValue,
        type: "new",
        [mainListOptionsKey]: `${addNewLabel} "${params.inputValue}"`,
      });
    }
    return filtered;
  };

  const handleGetOptionLabel = (option) => {
    if (typeof option === "string") {
      return option;
    }
    return option ? option[mainListOptionsKey] : null;
  };

  const handleGetOptionSelected = (option, value) => {
    if (value && IsObject(value) && IsObjectNotEmpty(value)) {
      return option[mainListOptionsKey] === value[mainListOptionsKey];
    } else if (
      option &&
      IsObject(option) &&
      IsObjectNotEmpty(option) &&
      value &&
      IsString(value) &&
      IsNotEmpty(value)
    ) {
      return option[mainListOptionsKey] === value;
    } else {
      return option === value;
    }
  };

  const handleEmptyValue = (valueParam) => {
    /**
     * TODO:: Add these in utility folder.
     */
    if (isSelectMultiple) {
      return value && IsArrayNotEmpty(value)
        ? value
        : valueParam && IsArrayNotEmpty(valueParam)
        ? valueParam
        : [];
    } else {
      if (IsObject(valueParam) || IsObject(value)) {
        return IsNotUndefined(value) &&
          value !== null &&
          IsObjectNotEmpty(value)
          ? value
          : IsNotUndefined(valueParam) &&
            valueParam !== null &&
            IsObjectNotEmpty(valueParam)
          ? valueParam
          : null;
      } else if (IsString(valueParam) || IsString(value)) {
        return IsNotEmpty(value)
          ? value
          : IsNotEmpty(valueParam)
          ? valueParam
          : null;
      }
    }
  };

  const handleOnBlur = () => {
    if (IsFunction(onBlur)) {
      onBlur();
    }
  };

  const autocompleteValue = handleEmptyValue(autovalue);

  const inputRequired =
    required === true &&
    (isSelectMultiple
      ? !IsArrayNotEmpty(autocompleteValue)
      : !IsNotEmpty(autocompleteValue));

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      className={className}
      multiple={isSelectMultiple}
      value={autocompleteValue}
      filterSelectedOptions={filterSelectedOptions}
      id={id}
      size={size}
      ChipProps={ChipProps}
      disableClearable={disableClearable}
      popupIcon={popupIcon}
      openOnFocus={openOnFocus}
      blurOnSelect={blurOnSelect}
      options={listOptions}
      limitTags={limitTags}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
      disabled={disabled}
      filterOptions={handleFilterOptions}
      getOptionLabel={handleGetOptionLabel}
      getOptionSelected={handleGetOptionSelected}
      
      name={name}
      onBlur={handleOnBlur}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <div>
       <TextField
            {...params}
            id={renderInputId ? renderInputId : label}
            variant={variant}
            label={!labelAtTop && label}
            className={textFieldClassName}
            required={inputRequired}
            //onChange={()=>{}}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            fullWidth={fullWidth}
            InputLabelProps={inputLabelProps}
            helperText={helperText}
            error={error}           
          /> 
        </div>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default TypeaheadField;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see more about your code to have a better context. The first suggestion is to use the prop anchorEl and reference your Textfield. You can find more about it and examples in the documentation here:

https://material-ui.com/es/components/popper/

And also I don't know if you are using the Autocomplete component directly so let me know if you are.

Comment: Thanks for your time @LittleOrange . Basically, I have written a GENERIC AutoComplete which consumes ALL the possible props the AutoComplete Variants(Grouped, Limit Tags) can have. I refer this across my application. Added the ENTIRE source code for the AutComplete in my main question above.

Comment: The Popper code that I had shared was JUST to fix the options to the Autocomplete otherwise I dont actually need it. I would rather like to have the Autocomplete do the option s cling in the UI all by itself DEFAULT. But sadly that is not the case here.